# Puzzle: Gosh! What's that Word...?

Tags: lateral-thinking

The puzzle starts below:

> ...Even though is written with 10, sometimes can only be written with 9 letters, and maybe 5 letters!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer:

> The phrase "Even though" is written with 10 letters, the word "sometimes" is written with 9, and "maybe" has 5 letters. Not sure what answer I'm supposed to give here.

Comment: if that's the answer this should probably be tagged as a lateral thinking puzzle, no?